# how to provide a custom code func to encodable object

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, codable

There is a way to make my on ***code*** function for my codable struct,
the problem I'm facing is that I can encode it from network but not decode from userdefaults. Here is the implementation of the struct.

```
struct profile: Codable{
    var id: Int?
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var description: String?
    var gender: String?
    var birthDate: Date?
    var smoke: Bool?
    var findHouse: Bool?
    var hasRoom: Bool?
    var sociable: Int?
    var ordered: Int?
    var athlete: Int?
    var party: Int?
    var domestic:Int?
    var gamer: Int?
    var usersId: Int?
    var imageId: Int?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var image: imageModel?
    var tags: [String]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName =  "last_name"
        case description
        case gender
        case birthDate = "birth_date"
        case smoke
        case findHouse = "find_house"
        case hasRoom = "has_room"
        case sociable
        case ordered
        case athlete
        case party
        case domestic
        case gamer
        case usersId = "users_id"
        case imageId = "image_id"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case image
        case tags
    }
    init(){

    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        print("going to decode from decoder showing results")
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.id = (try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .id))
        print("id value \(self.id)")
        self.firstName = (try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .firstName))
        print("name value \(self.firstName)")
        self.lastName = (try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lastName))
        print("lastname value \(lastName)")
        self.description = (try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .description))
        print("description value \(description)")
        self.gender = (try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .gender))
        print("gender value \(gender)")
        if let date = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .birthDate){
            print("date value \(date)")
            self.birthDate = Date(fromString: String(date.dropLast(10)), format: .custom("yyyy-MM-dd"))
            print("after conversion \(self.birthDate)")
        }else{
            self.birthDate = nil
        }
        self.smoke = (try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .smoke)) == 0 ? false : true
        print("smoke value \(smoke)")
        self.findHouse = (try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .findHouse)) == 0 ? false : true
        print("findhouse value \(findHouse)")
        self.hasRoom = (try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .hasRoom)) == 0 ? false : true
        print("has romm value \(hasRoom)")
        self.sociable = (try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .sociable))
        print("sociable value\(sociable)")
        self.ordered = (try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .ordered))
        print("orderder value \(ordered)")
        self.athlete = (try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .athlete))
        print("athlete value \(athlete)")
        self.party = (try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .party))
        self.domestic = (try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .domestic))
        self.gamer = (try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .gamer))
        self.usersId = (try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .usersId))
        self.imageId = (try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .imageId))
        if let date = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .createdAt){
            self.createdAt = Date(fromString: String(date.dropLast(10)), format: .custom("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        }else {
            self.createdAt = nil
        }
        if let date = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .updatedAt){
            self.updatedAt = Date(fromString: String(date.dropLast(10)), format: .custom("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        }else{
            self.updatedAt = nil
        }
        self.image = (try values.decodeIfPresent(imageModel.self, forKey: .image))
        self.tags = (try values.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .tags))
    }

}
```

This is the code to save to userdefaults.standard:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(requestManager.instance.user) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "user")
        if let json = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("reading value in userDefault \(json)")
        }
    }
```

so when I try to decode from userDefaults with this code:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let user = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "user"){
            print("data for user \(user)")
            do{
                let question = try decoder.decode(profile.self, from: user)
                print("birthDate from decoder \(question.birthDate)")
                print("id from decoder \(question.id)")
                print("name from decoder \(question.firstName)")
                if question.id != nil {
                    print("the id is not Nil \(question)")
                    requestManager.instance.user = question
                }

            }catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                print("el valor de birthDate in \(requestManager.instance.user.birthDate)")
            }
        }
```

After this I got those messages in console

> going to decode from decoder. 
>   id value Optional(3). 
>   name value Optional("Yoel "). 
>   Data cannot be read because does not have the right format.

What I guess is date type in fields birthDate, createdAt and updatedAt.

So what I want to try is to create a custom encoder because in decoder is expecting a String and should be returning a Date value.

Comment: If you change the types in `init(from` you have to do the opposite in `encode(`

Comment: is not necesary to create a encode funtion i allready did the encode funtion but that not solve the main problem of saving to userdefaulft.

Comment: It is indeed necessary. For example you encode `hasRoom` as `Bool` (with the synthesized encoder) but you decode it as `Int` which causes a type mismatch. With respect and no offense but your entire struct is a mess. 

Comment: the problem here is what i got from endpoint if was a bool value true or false that would be nice but indeed is bool value with 0 and 1 so if i make then Int have to make a validation for only 0 and 1 so is clear a bool just not retorned from endpoint

Comment: Nevertheless if you use the full `Codable` protocol all encoded and decoded types must match.

Comment: i''ll edit the question to show the encode function

Answer (score 0):

Date conforms to the codable Protocol on its own. Why do you try to do some custom decoding on your own in your `init(from decoder: Decoder)`? You should not try to decode it as a string. I just tried a very small implementation like this:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

var str = "Hello, playground"

struct Person:Codable {
    var name:String
    var birthDate:Date
}
func test (){
    let pascal = Person(name: "Pascal", birthDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: -26.6 * 365 * 24 * 3600))
    print(pascal)
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(pascal) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "person")
    }

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "person"),
          let person = try? decoder.decode(Person.self, from: data) else {
             print("damn")
             return
    }
    print(person)
}

test()
```

Comment: the thing is birthdate come as string from endpoint so i have to format it to make a custom date otherwise the encoder and decoder fails. the birthdate format is like "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand. You are using a different format in your decode: `Date(fromString: String(date.dropLast(10)), format: .custom("yyyy-MM-dd"))`. So you're getting a JSON object and you just want to transform it into a swift object?

Comment: im just adjusting to the date format as recived from network request what i got is a string with this format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" so i made a droplast(10) to encode as mmmm-YY-dd not using time part

Comment: Now I understand your problem. You implemented init(from: aDecoder) in order to init your struct with the json response you get from the server. Now you're running into the problem that you cannot decode the json you read from the UserDefaults, because your not implementing the encode function as suggested in the comments under your post. This leads to the birthdate being encoded as a date while you want to decoder a string in your decode method.

Comment: In this case overwriting the decoder isn't the way to go. Simply implement the encode with encoder function in your struct and have it encoder your date as a string in the same format you're getting from the server. Otherwise you could simply save the date string in your struct all the time and just have a computed property that translate the string into a date object, when you need it.